# Breakpoint indicators do not show up

Tags: visual-studio-2010

For a short time now I have had a problem or pain with the Breakpoint indicators, they do not show, yes I have the margin activated ( small grey stripe down the left side of the margin ). I have uninstalled all extensions, addins etc still no breakpoint indicator I have also deleted the .suo file with no go also. This is a major pain more than anything else. Anyone who has had this problem please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I once had this problem with VS2008. My solutions wasn't pretty, I had to reinstall it.